# How do I use alpha version of Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use alpha version of rails for my app. It's not available on rubygems.org, so I use this in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'master' # Use rails 6.0.0.alpha, FIXME: to be updated on rails release
```

`bundle install` went though:

```
...
Installing sprockets 3.7.2
Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Using rails 6.0.0.alpha from git://github.com/rails/rails.git (at master@5df4efd)
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 40 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

But `rails --version` shows weird output (I'm using RVM on Mac):

```
rails --version
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

But `bundle info rails` seems OK:

```
The git source `git://github.com/rails/rails.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
  * rails (6.0.0.alpha 5df4efd)
    Summary: Full-stack web application framework.
    Homepage: http://rubyonrails.org
    Path: /Users/ro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bundler/gems/rails-5df4efd2fd08
```

How do I fix my alpha `rails` command?

Comment: Another way to solve this is to use `bundle exec rails` or run the binstub `bin/rails`.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with

`rvm remove ruby-2.3.1` (old version of ruby)

I also had old gemset, commands like `rvm gemset list_all` and `rmv gemset list` can be helpful.